# Data Partitioning & Multi-tenancy With InsightEdge

Tags: insightedge

As I understand data partitioning in XAP, it is defined at the space level i.e. there are primary and back copies of a space. This partitioning cannot be controlled at a more granular level i.e. for e.g. in case of dynamic models at the document type level.

In my use case I have dynamic models that include facts (large datasets) and dimensions (small datasets). I would want to partition the facts but keep a copy of the dimensions on every node in the cluster. By defining a routing index I could specify a property in the fact document to be the partitioning key.

1. How do I make the dimensions (small datasets) available on all the XAP slave nodes so that they speed up the performance while performing joins with various fact documents?
2. Can I re-partition a document type if my routing property changes at run-time?
3. In a multi-tenant deployment (tenant = customer) I imagine designing a space per tenant and securing it by a username/password would be the right approach. If for some reason a space instance for a client gets corrupted. Does it affect other spaces? How can I restore one space in a multi-tenant clustered deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for GigaSpaces as the PM for XAP and InsightEdge. Hope this helps:

1. The typical data modeling approach to facts and dimensions would by routing facts with dimensions. Meaning, the facts routing key would be the same value as the dimension's key. This guarantees data locality when accessing many dimension objects that are associated with a specific fact. This is a good reference: http://docs.gigaspaces.com/sbp/modeling-your-data.html 
   If you are looking to join dimensions across many partitions, then there are two approaches: 1) Either use executor based remoting services and invoke a method using broadcast mode (http://docs.gigaspaces.com/xap120/executor-based-remoting.html#broadcast-remoting) or the simpler approach: 2) use Spark SQL from InsightEdge
2. The routing property is fixed once you specify the space type descriptor, it cannot be changed at runtime from a field to another. If you're looking to change it's value, then a simple "take" operation followed by a value change then space write should do.
3. It is the right approach if you want to isolate tenants at the JVM level. No, this won't affect other spaces. The best way to recover a space after a restart (from a persistent store) is to use the Space Data Source API.